How to develop x86 EXE files on ARM?
I have recently purchased an M4 Pro MacBook Pro. I want to know how to create .exe files using both C++ and Pyinstaller. Is it possible to do this?
I have installed Parallel Desktop and have ARM Windows on it I want to know how to create x86 compatible executables any ideas how to do that??

if your targeting windows x86, you need a compiler that can cross-compile. I dont believe pyinstaller has that capability and needs to be created on a machine with the same architecture as the target.
